# AddViewLocalization on IServiceCollection no longer exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

this should be a simple one. I'm tring to run AddViewLocalization and AddDataAnnotationsLocalization on an *IServiceCollection*, but am getting

> "'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
>   'AddViewLocalization' and the best extension method overload
>   'MvcLocalizationMvcBuilderExtensions.AddViewLocalization(IMvcBuilder,
>   LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat, Action)'
>   requires a receiver of type 'IMvcBuilder'"

The code:

```
    services.AddLocalization(o =>
    {
        o.ResourcesPath = Const.LocalizationResourcePath;
    })
        .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix, options => options.ResourcesPath = Const.LocalizationResourcePath)
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

this worked just fine before updating to asp.net core 2.1

what assembly do I need to reference?

Comment: Documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 4):

You are doing this:

```
services.AddViewLocalization();
```

Where you should actually be calling the `AddViewLocalization()` method as an extension of `AddMvc()`, for example:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization();
```

Comment: I've just added my code. please take a look if you can

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this solution:

```
services.AddLocalization(o =>
{
    o.ResourcesPath = Const.LocalizationResourcePath;
})
    .AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix, options => options.ResourcesPath = Const.LocalizationResourcePath)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```